# Splicing 6+ Wires

Tags: diy

My project contains a 12V parallel circuit and multiple switches.  What is the preferred way to splice 6+ 12AWG wires together.  My first thought was using butt connectors with 3 on each side, but at 12AWG not sure I'll have enough room with standard connectors.

Comment: Is there a [Wago connector](https://www.wago.com/gb/electrical-interconnections/discover-installation-terminal-blocks-and-connectors/221) that suits your requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was wiring up +12V & GND wiring for some low voltage circuits I used connectors like these with very good results.

[image]

<sup>[Picture Source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0107SYYGU)</sup>

These work well with either solid or stranded conductors in a range of sizes from 24 AWG to 12 AWG. They are rated for circuits up to 20A.

These come in sizes of 2, 3, and 5 common connections. If you need more than 5 connections you just have to jumper two connectors together with a short wire. With two 5 position units jumpered together you would achieve ability to connect 8 additional wires together.

Comment: Just be careful with the levers. They snap down with a surprising amount of force, and it can sting!

Comment: Never had the hard snap experience but maybe with 12 awh solid wire.

Comment: @Hearth The new design (as shown in the image) is much easier on the finger tips, in my limited experience.

Comment: The new design parts as pictured are the ones I have used and the levers operate with ease.

Answer (score 1):

Butt connectors can work but you just need to make sure that you match your wires' combined cross-sectional area to the connector. We have a circuit that requires 12 16AWG power and 12 16AWG ground connections to be spliced together and connected to a single 6AWG wire for each branch.  We use 6AWG butt connectors that are sized appropriately.  For 6 12AWG wires, you're in 4AWG territory so the crimper might be prohibitively priced.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution for restricted space: https://www.instructables.com/Soldering-multiple-wires-for-a-distribution-joint/